# Using Haskell to extend Perl?

Tags: perl, haskell, ffi

Has anyone ever written a Haskell extension to Perl? Maybe something simple, like a function that calculates the fib. sequence? I'm interested in using Haskell, and I see some overlap between the Haskell and Perl community. Any pointers to Haskell / Perl projects, or cool things that manage to use both of these? I've seen [Language::Haskell](http://search.cpan.org/~autrijus/Language-Haskell-0.01/lib/Language/Haskell/API.pm) -which is only an interpreter- but it seems poorly documented, 6 years old, and [lots of fail](http://search.cpan.org/~autrijus/Language-Haskell-0.01/).

Is it possible to build extentions to Perl using ghci comparable to using XS (something I don't claim to know anything about)? I realize this question is probably all kinds of wrong, and badly worded. I'm attempting two things that I know little about - Haskell and extending Perl (which have both always interested me). Feel free to edit this.

Comment: ...because why should someone settle for just unreadable code OR unpredictable running times when they can have both!  :-P

Comment: hahah upvoted for horribly inaccurate, but amusing.

Comment: :) Sorry I can't offer you any real advice on this.  Good luck!

Comment: I must admit that Perl and Haskell do seem to be leading the rest of the programming language world on "use of arcane infix operators".

Comment: Poking around in the Pugs source code might be interesting (Perl6 implementation in Haskell)

Answer (score 2):

The closest work was Inline::Haskell I think, during the pugs / perl6 time.

You can also embed Perl5 in a Haskell program: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HsPerl5

The Haskell FFI happily supports calling into Haskell from other languages, but I'm not sure this is sensible in the larger scheme of things. Sounds like *you're doing it wrong.*

Comment: Where did you get Inline::Haskell from? I can't find it on CPAN, and the only thing I found relating to it was [this post on perlmonks on a similar tune](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=369242).

Comment: I believe it was part of Pugs itself, rather than a separate package.

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps worth noting here that you can write shell scripts in Haskell as well using runhaskell:

```
#! /usr/bin/env runhaskell
```

There's [HSH](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HSH) for mixing shell expressions into Haskell programs.

And the [Simple UNIX Tools Haskell wiki page](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Simple_Unix_tools) is full of ideas too.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to Perl but more about [Scripting in Haskell](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/11/scripting-in-haskell)